# vba range (cells(), cells()) copy past to other worksheet with out activating the other worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a cell in a worksheet named `A` and I have to copy it then paste it to `Range(Cells(23, 60), cells(23, 78))` of worksheet called `B`.

How should I do ?

I thought about using dynamic cell references like : `copyrange = Range(Cells(696, 60), Cells(696, 60))`.

Answer (score 4):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim wsFrom As Worksheet, wsTo As Worksheet
    Dim CopyFrom As Range, CopyTo As Range
    Dim r1 As Long, r2 As Long, r3 As Long, r4 As Long
    Dim c1 As Long, c2 As Long, c3 As Long, c4 As Long

    Set wsFrom = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("A")
    Set wsTo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("B")

    r1 = 696: c1 = 60
    r2 = 696: c2 = 60
    r3 = 23: c3 = 60
    r4 = 23: c4 = 78

    With wsFrom
        Set CopyFrom = .Range(.Cells(r1, c1), .Cells(r2, c2))
    End With

    With wsTo
        Set CopyTo = .Range(.Cells(r3, c3), .Cells(r4, c4))
    End With

    CopyFrom.Copy CopyTo
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really give us a lot to go on here, so I'll post one way and see if it gets you going:

```
Sub test()
Dim columnReferenceSource     As Long
Dim rowReferenceSource        As Long
Dim columnReferenceDest       As Long
Dim rowReferenceDest          As Long
Dim r                         As Range

rowReferenceSource = 696
columnReferenceSource = 60

rowReferenceDest = 23
columnReferenceDest = 60

Set r = Range(Sheets("A").Cells(rowReferenceSource, columnReferenceSource), Sheets("A").Cells(rowReferenceSource, columnReferenceSource + 18))

r.Copy Destination:=Sheets("B").Cells(rowReferenceDest, columnReferenceDest)

End Sub
```

Obviously you'll have to set the row and column numbers for your situation.  If you can provide more details as to what you're trying to do, I'm sure we can give a more complete answer.  For instance, how do you go about determining the source and destination range?

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
Dim r As Range
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(696, 60).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range(.Cells(23, 60), .Cells(23, 78))
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the worksheet's name before `cells()`:

```
sub CopyA_PasteB()

dim wb as Workbook
dim wsA as worksheet
dim wsB as worksheet

set wb = Workbooks("WORKBOOK NAME")
set shA = wb.Worksheets("A")
set shB = wb.Worksheets("B")

shA.Range(shA.Cells(696, 60), shA.Cells(696, 60)).Copy
shB.Range("A1").Paste     'replace with your destination

End sub
```